How to mock Files.walk(Paths.get(dropLocation))) using mockito?
How can we mock the below method using mockito?
public static List<File> getFilesPath(String dropLocation) throws IOException{
        try(Stream<Path> streamPath = Files.walk(Paths.get(dropLocation))){
            return streamPath
                    .map(Path::toFile)
                    .filter(File::exists)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

I tried the below logic with no luck.
@Mock
    private StepContribution stepContribution;
    @Mock
    private ChunkContext chunkContext;
    @Mock
    private Stream<Path> streamPath;
    @Mock
    private Path path;
    
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
        //PowerMockito.mockStatic(Paths.class);
        
        Path p = Paths.get("Test");
        
        when(p).thenReturn(p);
        when(Files.walk(path)).thenReturn(streamPath);
        when(streamPath.count()).thenReturn(100L);
        
        
        tasklet = new HistoricAutoBorrowRequestTasklet();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testTasklet() throws Exception {
        RepeatStatus repeatStatus = tasklet.execute(stepContribution, chunkContext);
    }

